# Restore my previous font [before update]

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, urxvt

I just updated from 6.0.9 to wheezy 7.4, rebooted and everything is working alright so far, but my font (not system fixed though) - for example used in rxvt/urxvt - now is wider: it's gotten additional pixels in spaces between words and symbols. Looks like this: [image: this] h

Actually it's not that obvious in that picture, but I hope you get the point.
My `~/.fonts.conf` has in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
<const>rgb</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
<const>hintslight</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
<const>lcddefault</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="autohint">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

I've tried different options in `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config` but nothing really helped.

Any hint what to do / how to resolve the issue? I'm using Windowmaker as my graphical shell btw. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your display properties? It's possible that your resolution got changed to a different aspect ratio that results in fonts looking stretched out.

Comment: Thanks, but no. Same resolution, and the problem is persistent only with... urxvt :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was - it only appeared in urxvt-unicode.

> Urxvt can have problems with the spacings of some fonts (eg Terminus),
>   an option has been introduced in the latest version (9.07)

It's fixed with `URxvt*letterSpace: -1` in `~/.Xdefaults`